# How do I get the build id for a game on steam?

Tags: python, parsing, steam, steam-web-api

for example the steamdb site lays out all the information about game updates, such as cs go and others. The question is where do they get the build id value from? I would also like to parse this information so that I know about the release of updates immediately. But not from them, but from the source.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEGpk.png)

Answer (score 0):

SteamDB uses [SteamKit](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit) to communicate with Steam. If you just want the current Build ID for an App you could use the Steam console ( steam://open/console ) and give a command like `app_info_print <app-id>` which includes the Build ID's for all Branches of the provided App. This can be automated using [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD).

If you don't necessarily need the Build ID and are sufficient with information about the Update you could use the Steamworks Web API which provides the [ISteamNews](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamNews) Interface to query the news for the specified App.

For CS:GO the url you are looking for would be `https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v2/?appid=730`.
Do note that not every new build comes with patch notes. Especially considering Applications which are not developed by Valve.